# Twitter Bootstrap. Remove whitespace between <div span> elements in columns

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create framework for vacancies listing in pinterest-like way (infinite 5-columns wall with vacancies description) in Twitter Bootstrap using ruby-on-rails.

But I have a problem - there are whitespaces between row's elements , like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PStrE.png

I need to delete these whitespaces to show continuous canvas.

Code I use to generate wall:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @employer_vacancies.reverse.each do |employer_vacancy| %>
    <div class="span2 hero-unit left">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom:0px !important";> 
        <%= employer_vacancy.vacancy_title %>  
      </h2>     
      <br>
      <%= employer_vacancy.vacancy_description %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I believe it could be achieved by JavaScript, or maybe even by CSS.

Comment: Have you been thinking about assigning some background to the whole row? It may be the best idea, if your design is not responsive (otherwise it will look differently in different resolutions anyway).

Comment: Is a CSS3 solution acceptable? It can be done with simple css, but the solution might not be supported in IE until 9+ i would think.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think jQuery Masonry is the right tool for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS can't do this if the number of columns is variable, and you need it work in all common browsers.

Instead, use jQuery Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

There's also a no-framework version, Vanilla Masonry: http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).